# extract string with java-script

Tags: javascript

I have an URL like this

```
localhost:8080/myroot/dir1/dir2/myTestpage.do
```

I need to get the string upto the root like this

```
var myURL = "localhost:8080/myroot/";
```

I tried the slicing but did not work:

```
var str = "localhost:8080/myroot/dir1/dir2/myTestpage.do";   
var myURL = str.split("/").slice(-3, -2).toString();
```

How can I get the string upto "localhost:8080/myroot/" ?

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeewanaryal/hnVnm/1/)

How can I get that string from the url pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var str = "localhost:8080/myroot/dir1/dir2/myTestpage.do";
var myURL = str.split('/').slice(0,2).join('/') + '/';
```

Or more simply:

```
var myURL = str.split('/', 2).join('/') + '/';
```

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression like this:

```
var myURL = str.match(/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\//)[0];
```

Or this:

```
var myURL = str.match(/.*?\/.*?\//)[0];
```

Comment: awesome. worked perfectly. Thanks, I just closed with your answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Modifying you `var myUrl =` line will make it work

```
var myURL = str.split("/").slice(0, 2).toString().replace(",", "/") + "/";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this :

```
var myURL = str.split("/");
myURL = myURL[0] + '/' + myURL[1];
```

Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/hnVnm/2/

Comment: this is also great :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try `replace` or `match` :

```
myURL = myURL.match(/^(.*?\/){2}/)[0];
myURL = myURL.replace(/^((.*?\/){2}).*$/, '$1');
// (.*?\/){2} : everything until a slash, 2 times
```

Answer (score 1):

And just to have a regex solution also:

```
"localhost:8080/myroot/dir1/dir2/myTestpage.do".match(/^(https?:\/\/)?[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\//)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast and dirty:

```
var str = "localhost:8080/myroot/dir1/dir2/myTestpage.do";
var strSplit = str.split("/");
var myUrl = strSplit[0] + "/" + strSplit[1] + "/";
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a substring version of the answer:

```
var myURL = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('/', str.indexOf('/') + 1) + 1);
```

The key here is the second parameter of `indexOf`, which creates an offset to start searching from. The offset is *also* `str.indexOf('/')+1`, so it's finding the second forward slash as the end index for `substring`.